Configure KDevelop to recognize file extension as a glsl language file
How would I configure KDevelop to recognize a file extension and highlight the file appropriately.

.vert is recognized as OpenGL Shading Language (glsl)
.comp is not (compute shader, also glsl)


I got it to highlight my file by clicking Help, Find Action, and searching for glsl.
